# I want to separate only the tumor from (brain tumor MRI image) image that means active contour

Tags: python, numpy

Only the tumor is white and another part is black. How can I calculated the tumor area? I use windows as operating system and python3.How can brain area also calculated?

```
#Active Countour

image = cv2.imread(args["brain.png"])
shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 21, 51)
cv2.imshow("Input", image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(shifted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
its show:

  File "F:/Semesters/Thesis/New folder (2)/brine.py", line 157, in <module>
    image = cv2.imread(args["brain.png"])

NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

cv2.imread only needs the file name, just use cv2.imread("brain.png")

Comment: Tts doesn't show only the tumor area.It's show not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`image = cv2.imread("\brain.png")`

or

`image = cv2.imread(r" your full path")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this then, import argparse and set it up.
[image]

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.It showed this problem again

Comment: I see what went wrong now. `File "F:/Semesters/Thesis/New folder (2)/brine.py", line 157,`  Please change the New folder name. Your file path should not contain any spaces

Comment: Try to add `r"your file path that does not contain any spaces"`

Comment: I also tried this but it showed : runfile('C:/Users/Mahbuba/Desktop/co.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mahbuba/Desktop')
usage: co.py [-h] -i IMAGE
co.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

C:\Users\Mahbuba\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3334: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)